# Excel formula to subtract a different value based on conditions

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I write the following formula?

If cell A is greater than Cell B, Cell `C = C-A`; If cell B is greater than Cell A, cell `C = C-B`

I tried to write it like this:

```
=IF(OR(C3>A3,C3-A3),IF(C3>B3,C3-B3))
```

I have windows 10 and my browser is IE.

Comment: I think you can't, because the value of C3 would be always changing and never stop. You can try the following formula, but kepping the result in other cell, not in C3. The formula is =IF(A3>B3;C3-A3;C3-B3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want `C-A` if `A>B`, and `C-B` if `B>A`. If that's the case you can just use this formula:

`=IF(A1>B1,C1-A1,C1-B1)`

Which say that if `A>B` then do `C-A`, else do `C-B`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're just trying to subtract the greater value between `A` and `B`. You can make this function more modular by using `MAX()`, i.e. `=C3-MAX(A3,B3)`